# How to remap points on 2d plane to another plane with regression kind of approach?

Tags: regression, least-squares, geometric-transformation

The title can not be clear enough as I really don't know how to call this problem. Let me describe it briefly.

I have some points in coordinate system as (x,y). All points have to move to a new coordinate system (translating) for some need (assume that they move to new positions as reinforced). I have some sample values that I know where they have to be in new map. By the help of this information, I would like to be able to calculate new positions of new points on new map. What I want to accomplish is like calculating a formula or something (like regression, least squares fitting) that I can use it to be able to estimate new positions of new points (see the illustration below).

I don't know how to call this in terms of math, I searched but could not get what I want but I am sure there is a solution already to solve this kind of problems.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that the transformation is a linear map ... If it's not a linear map, it's potentially very hard to make such approximations. How have you obtained these results?

Comment: @MattiP. Actually it is not linear but not random neither. Points is correlated itself (for instance you can assume it a kind of rotation). But this does not need to be linear I think, this job could be done by a neural network and it would perform well but on the other side this is not that complicated to train a model but a simpler approach could exist I guess.

Comment: is the mapping conformal ... do right angles remain right angles post-transformation

Comment: can you express the transformation as a combination of rotation, translation and/or scaling?

Comment: It sounds like the word you're looking for might be "Interpolation".